# Why is posix_memalign() causing SIGKILL?

Tags: linux, memory-management, malloc

This code that calls `posix_memalign()` and then initializes the bytes eventually causes `SIGKILL`.  With `malloc()`, it doesn't.  Why?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<cstring>
#include<cassert>

void *p; // confuse the compiler to prevent optimizations.

int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 1600000; i++) {
        if ((i % 10000) == 0) {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
        int r = 0;
        r = posix_memalign(&p, 4096, sizeof(uint[1024])); // yes SIGKILL
        assert(r == 0);
 //       p = malloc(sizeof(uint[1024])); // no SIGKILL
        assert(p != NULL);
        memset(p, 4, sizeof(uint[1024])); 
    }
    return ((int*)(p))[0];
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ g++ -g -Wall  test.cpp -O3 -o test.exe && ./test.exe
...
1280000
1290000
1300000
1310000
Killed
$
```

Since it's `SIGKILL`, I can't catch it in GDB.

GCC version:

```
$gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none:amdgcn-amdhsa
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --with-target-system-zlib=auto --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --enable-cet --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-nvptx/usr,amdgcn-amdhsa=/build/gcc-11-XeT9lY/gcc-11-11.4.0/debian/tmp-gcn/usr --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
```

System version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux swanson-dev-10.67.190.1 5.15.0-76-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 15 19:16:32 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: More experimentation:  It works fine on my mac.

also fails on linux for `Linux 16309e220d95 3.10.0-1160.105.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 7 15:39:45 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Likely the process is killed by OOM killer. Do you see any messages in dmesg?

Comment: Each `malloc()` consumes 4096 bytes + small allocator metadata. For 1.6e6 iterations it's a little more than 6 Gb. Each `posix_memalign()` consumes 8192 bytes because of alignment. After 1310000 iterations it consumed almost 10 Gb. How much RAM and swap do you have?